# Login script without MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't know why this isn't working, I do not want to use MySQL. I just want to create a simple username and password that if correct takes the user to "process_login.php" and if not takes them to a random site.

```
    "<!doctype html>
    <?php
    <head>
        <title>"Chris's Crispy Chips and Cuccumber, Cheddar Cheese, and Carravan of Convienece located in Canada"</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='containter'>
                <div class="login">
                    <h2>Welcome to Le ScottsDoodle</h2>
                            <p>
                                <input type='text' name='myusername' value='' placeholder='Username' $user = ('admin')>
                                <input type='password' name='mypassword' value='' placeholder='Password' $pass = ('password')>
                            </p>
                        <p class='remember_me'>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='remember_me' id='remember_me'>
                            Remember me :*
                        </p>
                        <p class='submit'><input type='submit' onClick="SubmitForm(
                            if($user == "admin" && $pass == "password") {
                                header('Location: process_login.php');
                            } else {
                                header('Location: aehgufeih.php');
                            }
                            )" name='Login' value='Login'></p>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


    </body>
```

Comment: Have the form submit and process it in PHP. Don't use onclick/JS; that will allow any user to obtain username/password.... or submit the form values via ajax to a PHP page that checks the values. Don't store password/usernames client side.

Comment: Double check your format... you immediately switch to HTML (not echoed HTML) right after jumping into `<?php` ...

Comment: Yea, your code formatting is exceptionally weird I figured that was a bad paste job here. `"<!doctype html>
        <?php` Are you getting a 500 or blank page?

Comment: You also have two closing `</form>` tags without opening tags.  Please double check all of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you're trying to do.

```
<?php
@$user = $_POST['myusername'];
@$pass = $_POST['mypassword'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($user == "admin" && $pass == "password") {
        header('Location: process_login.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: aehgufeih.php');
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>"Chris's Crispy Chips and Cuccumber, Cheddar Cheese, and Carravan of Convienece located in Canada"</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='containter'>
        <div class="login">
            <h2>Welcome to Le ScottsDoodle</h2>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <input type='text' name='myusername' value='' placeholder='Username'>
                    <input type='password' name='mypassword' value='' placeholder='Password'>
                </p>
                <p class='remember_me'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='remember_me' id='remember_me'>
                    Remember me :*
                </p>
                <p class='submit'><input type='submit' name="submit"></p>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Should put the variable assignments (e.g. `$user = $_POST['myusername'];`) in the conditional. Notices will be thrown if reporting is on. Also add `exit();` after `header`.

Comment: The reason I put the variables up top instead of in the conditional is because normally when I'm doing this I'll be running a query and typing `$_POST['username']` over and over gets annoying real fast. See my updated answer to see an easy way to get rid of the notices.

Comment: You are assign or accessing the query in the wrong place in that case. The `@` operator should be avoided. `Make sure you are not hiding errors by using the @ syntax. This is not good practice, particularly during development when you want to be advised of errors.` -http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info